# How to change the background color of the action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, background-color

I was working hard to achieve this but I had no luck. What I tried to do is to change the background color from the style that I attached in my main style tag. This is my code:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item ></item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#2E495E</item>
</style>
```

Still nothing changed.
I get this in my application:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0i51.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the only style.xml you have? Else check if you are modifying
>   for the right API

Comment: Is this the only `style.xml` you have? Else check if you are modifying for the right **API**.

Comment: Thank you man. Now it works. But do I supposed to put the same code in all style xml files that I have or is it enough if I put it in the xml file that has the lowest API I am targeting?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure about that. I use a single file placed in single values folder.

Comment: It is okay. Your answer was helpful. If you could write it as an independent answer, I will approve it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it's probably the same problem you were having. Notice the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) say the following:

> each style property that you declare must be declared twice..

So my issue was I declared it for 2.1 and up, but not for 3.0 and greater so my Galaxy S4 of course could not see any changes to the colours I was making.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!--Support Library compatibility-->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>

    <!--Support Library compatibility-->
    <item name="background">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```